# Laravel 5 Ajax Internal Server Error 500

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I am using this to get my Ajax post call to work in a Laravel 5 app:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<?= csrf_token() ?>">

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

request = $.ajax({ 
          url: "/user", 
          type: "post", success:function(data){
          }, 
          data: {'email': email} ,beforeSend: function(data){console.log(data);} 
    });
```

I can see the token rendering correctly in the page source, but I still get the Internal Server Error 500 and the Ajax call fails.  Any idea what is happening?

EDIT:

Ajax Output:

```
POST http://vidvalize.dev/user 500 (Internal Server Error)n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4React.createClass.saveAndContinue @ script.js:37u @ react.min.js:12_.executeDispatch @ react.min.js:16a @ react.min.js:12s @ react.min.js:12c @ react.min.js:12r @ react.min.js:16d.processEventQueue @ react.min.js:12r @ react.min.js:15i.handleTopLevel @ react.min.js:15i @ react.min.js:15o.perform @ react.min.js:16d.batchedUpdates @ react.min.js:13i @ react.min.js:15v.dispatchEvent @ react.min.js:15


Object {readyState: 0}abort: (a){var b=a||u;return c&&c.abort(b),x(0,b),this}always: (){return e.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}complete: (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}done: (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}error: (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}fail: (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}getAllResponseHeaders: (){return 2===t?e:null}getResponseHeader: (a){var b;if(2===t){if(!f){f={};while(b=gb.exec(e))f[b[1].toLowerCase()]=b[2]}b=f[a.toLowerCase()]}return null==b?null:b}overrideMimeType: (a){return t||(k.mimeType=a),this}pipe: (){var a=arguments;return n.Deferred(function(c){n.each(b,function(b,f){var g=n.isFunction(a[b])&&a[b];e[f[1]](function(){var a=g&&g.apply(this,arguments);a&&n.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify):c[f[0]+"With"](this===d?c.promise():this,g?[a]:arguments)})}),a=null}).promise()}progress: (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}promise: (a){return null!=a?n.extend(a,d):d}readyState: 4responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵    <head>↵        <meta charset="UTF-8" />↵        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />↵        <style>↵            /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */↵            html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}↵↵            html { background: #eee; padding: 10px }↵            img { border: 0; }↵            #sf-resetcontent { width:970px; margin:0 auto; }↵                        .sf-reset { font: 11px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333 }↵            .sf-reset .clear { clear:both; height:0; font-size:0; line-height:0; }↵            .sf-reset .clear_fix:after { display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }↵            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:inline-block; }↵            .sf-reset * html .clear_fix { height:1%; }↵            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:block; }↵            .sf-reset, .sf-reset .block { margin: auto }↵            .sf-reset abbr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help; }↵            .sf-reset p { font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#868686; padding-bottom:20px }↵            .sf-reset strong { font-weight:bold; }↵            .sf-reset a { color:#6c6159; cursor: default; }↵            .sf-reset a img { border:none; }↵            .sf-reset a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }↵            .sf-reset em { font-style:italic; }↵            .sf-reset h1, .sf-reset h2 { font: 20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif }↵            .sf-reset .exception_counter { background-color: #fff; color: #333; padding: 6px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; float: left; display: block; }↵            .sf-reset .exception_title { margin-left: 3em; margin-bottom: 0.7em; display: block; }↵            .sf-reset .exception_message { margin-left: 3em; display: block; }↵            .sf-reset .traces li { font-size:12px; padding: 2px 4px; list-style-type:decimal; margin-left:20px; }↵            .sf-reset .block { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px 28px; margin-bottom:20px;↵                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;↵                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;↵                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 16px;↵                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 16px;↵                border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;↵                border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;↵                border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;↵                border-right:1px solid #ccc;↵                border-left:1px solid #ccc;↵            }↵            .sf-reset .block_exception { background-color:#ddd; color: #333; padding:20px;↵                -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 16px;↵                -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 16px;↵                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 16px;↵                -moz-border-radius-topright: 16px;↵                border-top-left-radius: 16px;↵                border-top-right-radius: 16px;↵                border-top:1px solid #ccc;↵                border-right:1px solid #ccc;↵                border-left:1px solid #ccc;↵                overflow: hidden;↵                word-wrap: break-word;↵            }↵            .sf-reset a { background:none; color:#868686; text-decoration:none; }↵            .sf-reset a:hover { background:none; color:#313131; text-decoration:underline; }↵            .sf-reset ol { padding: 10px 0; }↵            .sf-reset h1 { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 15px 28px; margin-bottom: 20px;↵                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;↵                -moz-border-radius: 10px;↵                border-radius: 10px;↵                border: 1px solid #ccc;↵            }↵        </style>↵    </head>↵    <body>↵                    <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">↵                <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>↵                                        <h2 class="block_exception clear_fix">↵                            <span class="exception_counter">1/1</span>↵                            <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException">FatalErrorException</abbr> in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php line 5" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">UserController.php line 5</a>:</span>↵                            <sp…>Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse</abbr>->handle() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array:{/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:124}() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php line 59" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">EncryptCookies.php line 59</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies">EncryptCookies</abbr>->handle() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array:{/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:124}() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode">CheckForMaintenanceMode</abbr>->handle() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array:{/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:124}() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 124" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 124</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 103" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 103</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func:{/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103}() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 103" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 103</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php line 118" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Kernel.php line 118</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->sendRequestThroughRouter() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php line 86" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Kernel.php line 86</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->handle() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/public/index.php line 54" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">index.php line 54</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>{main}() in <a title="/home/vagrant/code/vidvalize/public/index.php line 0" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">index.php line 0</a></li>↵    </ol>↵</div>↵↵            </div>↵    </body>↵</html>"setRequestHeader: (a,b){var c=a.toLowerCase();return t||(a=s[c]=s[c]||a,r[a]=b),this}state: (){return c}status: 500statusCode: (a){var b;if(a)if(2>t)for(b in a)q[b]=[q[b],a[b]];else v.always(a[v.status]);return this}statusText: "Internal Server Error"success: (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}then: (){var a=arguments;return n.Deferred(function(c){n.each(b,function(b,f){var g=n.isFunction(a[b])&&a[b];e[f[1]](function(){var a=g&&g.apply(this,arguments);a&&n.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify):c[f[0]+"With"](this===d?c.promise():this,g?[a]:arguments)})}),a=null}).promise()}__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many reasons for internal server error. It would be helpful to narrow down the problem, if you can post entire ajax response.

But if you think, it has to do with `csrf_token` try sending it as a request data like below,

```
request = $.ajax({ 
             url: "/user", 
             type: "post",  
             data: 'email=' + email + '&_token={{ csrf_token() }}',
             beforeSend: function(data){console.log(data);},
             success:function(data){}
         });
```

Comment: I'm sending the token and I used the global method of including the token as well.  It's still giving the error.  I'm not sure what the problem is.  The Error output seems to be just HTML output.

Comment: There is some other problem with code. ' FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 5:↵ Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37↵
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle() in Pipeline.php line 124'

Comment: what is that?  I'm not sure what that could be.

Answer (score 0):

Are there POST parameters you need to be sending?

Comment: I'm using a Laravel 5 resource; The route: Route::resource('user', 'UserController');